# How to use Visual Studio as your merge tool in Tower

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, git-tower

I'd like to use Visual Studio as the default merge tool in Tower. I've looked at the docs and the comparetools.jsons that ship with the installer, but unfortunately `vsDiffMerge /?` doesn't provide any useful information on what parameters go where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure Visual Studio 2017 as your merge tool in Tower, place `vs2017.json` in the following directory: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\fournova\Tower\Settings\CompareTools\`

Set the following contents and adjust the Visual Studio search path when needed:

```
{
  "DisplayName":           "Visual Studio 2017",
  "MinimumVersion":        "",
  "SupportsDiffChangeset": true,
  "SupportsDirectoryDiff": false,
  "DiffToolArguments":     "\"$LOCAL\" $REMOTE /t",
  "MergeToolArguments":    "\"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\" /m",
  "ApplicationRegistryIdentifiers": [
  ],
  "ApplicationPaths": [
      "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Preview\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\vsDiffMerge.exe",
      "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Preview\\Professional\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\vsDiffMerge.exe",
      "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Preview\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\vsDiffMerge.exe",  
      "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Preview\\TeamExplorer\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\vsDiffMerge.exe",  
      "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\vsDiffMerge.exe",
      "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\vsDiffMerge.exe",
      "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\vsDiffMerge.exe",
      "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\TeamExplorer\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\vsDiffMerge.exe"
  ]
}
```

Restart Tower and then select Visual Studio in the preferences window:

[image]

See also:

- https://jessehouwing.net/visual-studio-2017-merge-tool-in-tower/